# jquery load() is not loading the content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a hyperlink that when clicked, I want it to load the content from another file so the page doesn't have to refresh. The contents of the current ".container" should be replaced with the contents of ".container" from an external html file.

Here is my html

```
 <li> <a href="#" class="loader" id="indexLink">Chris Lebeau</a>
```

Here is my jQuery at the bottom of the page.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("#indexLink").click(function(event) {
     jQuery("div.container").html(ajax_load).load("index.html");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

When you click the first guy in the ORG chart @ http://frommesetc.com/test/org.html that .container should fade out, and the .container from index.html should fade in.

Comment: Where is the `load` function defined? Note that you are binding the click event handler to the container, not the link. Also, `<a href="load()"...` will simply try to load the page with name `load()`, it won't call the method `load` (if that was your intent). I don't see any connection between the HTML (the link) and your JavaScript code.

Comment: object.load is a jquery builtin

Comment: @Just: I'm talking about `<a href="load()">`.

Comment: @Justanotherdunce But `window.load` is not.

Comment: Im not to sure, i just found a jquery snippet on google, was hoping it would work. I guess I am missing some other function or something

Comment: Thats my ajaq script in its entirety

Comment: Well then your issue is that your using things that are undefined.

Comment: Can you link the script you found?

Comment: Im confused, I thought var loadUrl = "/index.html";  
    $(".container").click(function(){  
    $(".container").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);  was what I was defining. Im a noob!!

Comment: And this binds a click event handler to all elements with class `container`. If you click on any of those elements, the function will be executed and the content will be loaded. If you are new to jQuery/JavaScript, I recommend to read about some basics first: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: My two pages each are wrapped in a div.container. If I want the current page to fade out and load the.container from another page, do you know what that script should look like? Is it alot different from what I have now?

Comment: I changed the first class to button so it was hooked to my a tag but it's not loading the external file into the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.

Firstly you have no element with the class 'container' - therefore your click handler is actually doing nothing.

Also, if you have a listener for the click then there is no need to link to the JS function from a anchor.

Here is an example:

```
HTML:
<a class="button" href="#">Hello</a>
<div class="newcontent"></div>

JAVASCRIPT:
var loadingAnim = "<img src='img/ajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
var dataToLoad = "/index.html";
$("a.button").click(function(){
    $("div.newcontent")
        .html(loadingAnim)
        .load(dataToLoad);
});
```

Comment: Each of my pages have a class of container. When I click the .button link it should fade out the .container and load in the .container from an external file. I tried your script but still a no go.

Comment: I've tested this script and its working for me. Do you receive any error messages?

Just to explain how it works, a click listener is created for the anchor with the class of 'button'. 

When clicked it replaces the HTML content of 'div.newcontent' with the HTML in 'loadingAnim'.

It then loads the data from 'dataToLoad' and when its loaded replaces the HTML of 'div.newcontent' with the loaded data.

Answer (score 3):

You be missing a `javascript:` bit in your code:

`<a href="javascript:load()">Chris Lebeau</a>`

**EDIT**

You need to define the `load()` function as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...

var loadUrl = "/index.html";
function load() {
    $("div.container").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
}
</script>
```

This assumes you have some HTML element on the page with `class="container"`.

**EDIT 2**

Lastly, it is recommended now a days to use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).  To use this approach, do something like this:

```
<a href="index.html" id="chris_lebeau">Chris Lebeau</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#chris_lebeau").click(function(event) {
        jQuery("div.container").html(ajax_load).load("index.html");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

This is currently "best" way to do things, but if the `javascript:load()` method works, that should suffice.

Comment: I added the javascript:load() but it's still not working. Im not sure what the other comments are asking. It's a little over my head. All I have is the a tag that when clicked should make that jquery replace the current .container, with the content of .container from another file. Your suggestion was helpful though, I did need that, thanks!!

Comment: that got my loading gif to display but the page didnt load in the content. When I look in firebug I notice something funky at the end of the url, a series of numbers.    http://localhost:8080/RPG/ncm_master/index.html?_=1345171695524"  I have no idea what (?_=1345171695524") means

Comment: I think that is a "cache buster" (i.e. prevents the browser from caching the page by appending a random value to the URL).  Is there an HTML element on the page with `class="container"`?

Comment: I tried your new code, but doesnt work. Im not getting any errors though. Firebug says this (Object { originalEvent=Event click, type=

"click"

, timeStamp=

34291765

, more...}) Nothing happens on my page though.

Comment: Ahh cache buster, thats good to know!! I uploaded my example to ftp. If this can help anyone troubleshoot this. http://frommesetc.com/test/org.html when you click on the first guys name it should fade out that page and fade in the index.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution online.  I modified my code to use `event.preventDefault()` vs `return false`.  Also your original code was setting `cache: false`.  It looks like that has been removed, but wanting to confirm.

Comment: Yeah, I removed that and replace it with your code.I added your new script but it's still not working. Im really puzzled on how Im going to get this working. I never would of came up with adding (event.preventDefault();) Im googling that now to see what that means. Not sure what else could be wrong. Firebug returns no erros just (Object { originalEvent=Event click, type=

"click"

, timeStamp=

36123497

, more...})

Answer (score 0):

use

```
jQuery("div.container").load("index.html");
```